# Are the [x] and {x} functions defined for negative numbers?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

[x] is the whole part (floor) of x
{x} is the fractional (decimal) part of x

```
Ex:
[5,76] = 5;     [12/13] = 0;       [e] = 2;
{9/4}=0,25;     {69/2}=0,5;        {4}=0;
```

Are those functions defined for negative numbers and how?

Comment: The floor of a number $x$ is the greatest integer which is less than or equal to $x$.  We have for instance $\lfloor 2.7\rfloor = 2$ as $2$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $2.7$.  This definition is perfectly sound as it pertains to negative numbers as well... $\lfloor -3.9\rfloor = -4$ as $-4$ is the largest integer which is less than or equal to $-3.9$.

Comment: Now... as for fractional parts, the fractional part of a number $x$ is usually defined as $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.  For positive numbers, the result is as one would expect... just chop off everything that occurs prior to the decimal point... for instance $\{3.77\}=0.77$.  For negative numbers, recall how floor is defined and acts.  We would have $\{-6.25\} = 0.75$ noting that $-6.25 = (-7)+0.75$.  Do note that certain programming languages may do things differently and one should always confirm the behavior of such things according to the appropriate context.

Comment: Note that the fractional part of a negative number is not universally defined.  Some people define $x = \lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}$ for $x<0$ and others define $x = \lceil x \rceil + \{x\}$ for $x < 0$.  This leads to two different definitions, so we have to keep that in mind.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1461955) for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[x]$ is defined as the nearest integer less than $x$.

For example,

- $[4.78] = 4$.
- $[-4.78] = -5$.

$\{x\}$ is defined as

$$\{x\} = x - [x].$$

For example,

- $\{4.78\} = 4.78 - [4.78] = 4.78-4 = 0.78$.
- $\{-4.78\} = -4.78 - [-4.78] = -4.78-(-5) = 0.22$.